# Is there an appropriate way to send a message to all answerers of a question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I put a bounty on [Performance Problem: Delay on first request](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36147/performance-problem-delay-on-first-request) a few days ago and it's had a lot of really good/thorough answers.

Obviously I can only award the bounty to one person (that's going to be a pretty difficult choice in itself) but I can't help thinking it would be nice to at least say thank you the author's of the other answers, and perhaps be able to explain the choice.

Adding an answer would be inappropriate, as would editing the question. Commenting on the main question wouldn't notify the relevant people (and it would get buried anyway as there are quite a few comments there). Also commenting on each individual post would result in a lot of unnecessary noise.

Is there any acceptable/appropriate way to make this, I guess, announcement?

If not, do those of you who have been around the SE network for a while think this would have any chance of gaining traction as a feature request on the main site?

Comment: Seems to me that people will be monitoring a +500 rep bounty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the main site, the only way is adding a comment to each answer. Using the chat, you could write a post for which multiple users are notified, but that happens only if they have recently been in the chat room where you leave the post.

I don't think a feature that allows you to write a single comment for which all the users who answered the question would be notified will even be implemented: On Stack Exchange sites, comments are second-class citizens (if not third-class citizens); I don't think they are interested in any feature that would change how comments are used. Secondly, Stack Exchange sites are not social networks.

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be a bit 'social' for SE, I'll just leave it. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I agree that _Stack Exchange sites are not social networks_ :-), hence I also agree that can push multiple comments or anything equivalent would not be great. By cons, I think that the fundamental question remains of interest: to say it in other terms, **wouldn't it be fair that several equally valuable answers all get bounties**? So I thought to what I find a relatively simple way for that: first determine which answer will get the "accepted" bounty, then +1 to the other ones. This way, choosing who will get the "accepted" bounty becomes less difficult. In the other hand I'm not sure (and I c

Comment: @cFreed Each time you add a new bounty to the same question, you are not allowed to offer the same you offered on the previous bounty. If you are using bounties that way, you are using bounties in the wrong way: They are  just for the cases when you need an answer and nobody gave an helpful answer for you. Then, if you are know to offer multiple bounties for the same question, you are just going to get answers from users who hopes to get the bounty; this already happens, but opening multiple bounties for the same question would increase the phenomena.

Comment: Hmmm... I can understand this kind of reasoning, but what I called _fundamental question_ then remains unsolved. So what about that?